# django manytomany user auto fill the user field

Tags: python, django

I have 2 tables in my `models.py`. I'm trying to auto fill the user filed in the second table whatever user I select in my first table I tried to override the `save_model` in `admins.py` but it didn't work. Here is my `models.py` file:

```
class Company(models.Model):

    company_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique = True)
    user = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='company_user')
    objects = models.Manager()
    published = PublishedManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.company_name


class Group(models.Model):

    company_name = models.ForeignKey(Company, related_name = 'co_name', 
                                 on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    count = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    real_count = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    entry_date = models.DateTimeField()
    exit_date = models.DateTimeField()
    code = models.CharField(max_length = 10)
    code_date = models.DateTimeField()
    manifest = models.ImageField(upload_to='manifest/%m/%y', blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    user = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='group_user', blank=True)
    objects = models.Manager()
    published = PublishedManager()

    class Meta:
    
        ordering = ('-code_date',)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

my admins.py file

```
@admin.register(Group)
class GroupAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['id', 'company_name', 'code', 'code_date', 'count',
                    'real_count', 'entry_date', 'exit_date',
                    'manifest', 'created'
                    ]
    autocomplete_fields = ('user',)


@admin.register(Company)
class CompanyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['company_name']
    autocomplete_fields = ('user',)
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('company_name',)}
```

views.py

```
@login_required
def main_approval(request):

    groups = Group.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    context = {'groups': groups}
    return render(request, 'approval/main_list.html', context)
```

I'm trying to get the user in the `Company` class to be auto inserted in my `Group` class

Any advice?

Comment: You cannot handle this from models.py In my opinion you can do that from views.py

Comment: how can i do it so i can filter the objects to be as the user logged in @daneilJames

Comment: im trying to filter user to show the content to the user i select and i have to add the user manually to both table im trying to fill the user in the first tabel and its added to the second table with me having to add it

Comment: you must have model instance first and follow my answer below

Comment: can you post views.py too

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this in views.py

```
user = self.company_name.user.all()
```

Comment: okay but how can i filter the user from request.user  here im getting all the user what im trying to do is adding specific user to the company table and it should be auto insert it in the group table so i can filter all objects in group table by request.user